# D3.js: Import file changing with a slider

Tags: javascript, d3.js, import, data-visualization

I am building a slider on a D3.js visualization.

I want the user to select a year on the slider and the slider to retrieve the data from a file, that in the name has the year that it was selected in the slider.

For that, I have added in the app.js file:

```
function update(year){
     slider.property("value", year);
     d3.select(".year").text(year);
     // us_data.style("fill", function(d) {
     //     return color(d.properties.years[year][0].rate)
     // });
}


var slider = d3.select(".slider")
    .append("input")
    .attr("type", "range")
    .attr("min", 2009)
    .attr("max", 2013)
    .attr("step", 1)
    .on("input", function() {
         var year = this.value;
         update(year);
     });

update(2013);
```

As I intend to read the year selected selected in the slider in order to pickup data from a file with the name of the year, I have added an `id` to the `h2` that will change when the slider moves on index.html:

```
<h2 id="vardatayear" class="year"></h2>
        <div class="slider"></div>
```

Considering that the "vardatayear" will influence the file that I want to import, I have created a variable to retrieve that value, and/or if it comes empty, retrieve 2013 (by default):

```
var honeyyear = document.getElementById("vardatayear").value || 2013;
```

Being my import as the following:

```
d3.json( `data/HoneyProduction-${honeyyear}.json`, function( honey_data ){...
```

I am inspiring my code in [this slider](http://bl.ocks.org/dougdowson/raw/9832019/), but when I change the year, the map stays the same, as the change in the slider is not affecting the file path in the import.
Any guidance in the process is appreciated.

---

### **Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>VI - Gonçalo Peres</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img id="logo" src="img/logo.png"></a>
            <br>
            <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
                <a href="#">Contexto</a>
                <a href="#">1.ª Codificação Visual</a>
                <a href="#">2.ª Codificação Visual</a>
                <a href="#">3.ª Codificação Visual</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
        <br>
        <br>
    </nav>
    <div id="intro">
        <h2>1.ª Codificação Visual</h2>
        <span>Lorem ipsum.</span><br>
        <span>Lorem Ipsum.</span><br>
    </div>
    <div id="legenda">
        <h4>Legenda</h4>
        <span>Lorem ipsum.</span><br>
        <span>Lorem ipsum.</span><br>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="content">
        <h1>U.S. Department of Agriculture - Honey Production, 2009-2013</h1>
        <h2 id="vardatayear" class="year"></h2>
        <div class="slider"></div>
        <div id="map"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="chart"></div>
    <div id="buttons">
        <button type="button" class="panning up"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i></button>
        <button type="button" class="panning down"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></button>
        <button type="button" class="panning left"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></button>
        <button type="button" class="panning right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
        <button type="button" class="zooming in"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
        <button type="button" class="zooming out"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
    </div>

    <div id="note">
        <span>Gonçalo Peres | <b><a class="website" href="http://goncaloperes.com/" target="_blank">GoncaloPeres.com</a></b></span><br>
        <span>Data from: <a class="website" href="https://public.enigma.com/datasets/u-s-department-of-agriculture-honey-production-2013/41cf2441-e96f-4113-a02f-402d167a9cd8" target="_blank">Enigma Public</a></span>
    </div>

    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

### **app.js**

```
//  Define width and height
var chart_width     =   800;
var chart_height    =   600;


// Define the color scale
var color           =   d3.scaleQuantize().range([
    "#f7fbff",
    "#deebf7",
    "#c6dbef",
    "#9ecae1",
    "#6baed6",
    "#4292c6",
    "#2171b5",
    "#08519c",
    "#08306b"
]);


// Navbar
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "100%";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}


// Define the Tooltip
var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip");


// Define the Map Projection
var projection      =   d3.geoAlbersUsa()
    .translate([ 0,0 ]);
var path            =   d3.geoPath( projection );


// Create SVG
var svg             =   d3.select("#chart")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", chart_width)
    .attr("height", chart_height);


// Zoom
var zoom_map        =   d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([ 0.5, 3.0 ])
    .translateExtent([
        [ -1000, -500 ],
        [ 1000, 500 ]
    ])
    .on( 'zoom', function(){
    // console.log( d3.event );
    var offset      =   [
        d3.event.transform.x,
        d3.event.transform.y
    ];
    var scale       =   d3.event.transform.k * 1100;

    projection.translate( offset )
        .scale( scale );

    svg.selectAll( 'path' )
        .transition()
        .attr( 'd', path );

    svg.selectAll( 'circle' )
        .transition()
        .attr( "cx", function(d) {
            return projection([d.longitude, d.latitude])[0];
        })
        .attr( "cy", function(d) {
            return projection([d.longitude, d.latitude])[1];
        });
});

var map             =   svg.append( 'g' )
    .attr( 'id', 'map' )
    .call( zoom_map )
    .call(
        zoom_map.transform,
        d3.zoomIdentity
            .translate( chart_width / 2, chart_height / 2 )
            .scale( 1 )
    );

map.append( 'rect' )
    .attr( 'x', 0 )
    .attr( 'y', 0 )
    .attr( 'class', "mapsvg")
    .attr( 'width', chart_width )
    .attr( 'height', chart_height )
    .attr( 'opacity', 0 );


// Load Data
var honeyyear = document.getElementById("vardatayear").value || 2013;

// if(!honeyyear){
//     honeyyear  = 2013
// }

// Select what are we analyzing
// var honeyattribute = document.getElementById('some_input_id').value;

d3.json( `data/HoneyProduction-${honeyyear}.json`, function( honey_data ){

    color.domain([
        d3.min( honey_data, function(d){
            return d.average_price_per_pound;
        }),
        d3.max( honey_data, function(d){
            return d.average_price_per_pound;
        })
    ]);

    // Load GeoJson Data
    d3.json( 'data/us.json', function( us_data ){
        us_data.features.forEach(function(us_e, us_i){
            honey_data.forEach(function(h_e,h_i){
                if( us_e.properties.name !== h_e.state ){
                    return null;
                }

                us_data.features[us_i].properties.average_price_per_pound   =   parseFloat(h_e.average_price_per_pound);
            });
        });


        // Bind Data
        map.selectAll( 'path' )
            .data( us_data.features )
            .enter()
            .append( 'path' )
            .attr( 'd', path )
            .attr( 'fill', function( d ){
                var average_price_per_pound         =   d.properties.average_price_per_pound;
                return average_price_per_pound ? color( average_price_per_pound ) : '#525252';
            })
            .attr( 'stroke', '#fff' )
            .attr( 'stroke-width', 1 )
            .on("mouseover", function(d) {
                tooltip.transition()
                    .duration(250)
                    .style("opacity", 1);
                tooltip.html("<strong>" + d.properties.name + "</strong>" + "<br/>" + "Average price per pound (cents): " +
                    (d.properties.average_price_per_pound))
                    .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 15) + "px")
                    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
            })
            .on("mouseout", function(d) {
                tooltip.transition()
                    .duration(250)
                    .style("opacity", 0);
            })
            .append('title')

            // // For the simple tooltip
            // .text(d => d.properties.average_price_per_pound);

        // draw_cities();

    });



    // Legend
    const x = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain(d3.extent(color.domain()))
        .rangeRound([500, 750]);

    const g = svg.append("g")
        .attr( "class", "legend" )
        .attr("transform", "translate(0,40)");

    g.selectAll("rect")
        .data(color.range().map(d => color.invertExtent(d)))
        .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("height", 8)
        .attr("x", d => x(d[0]))
        .attr("width", d => x(d[1]) - x(d[0]))
        .attr("fill", d => color(d[0]));

    g.append("text")
        .attr("class", "caption")
        .attr("x", x.range()[0])
        .attr("y", -6)
        .attr("fill", "#fff")
        .attr("text-anchor", "start")
        .attr("font-weight", "bold")
        .text('Average Price per Pound (cents)');

    g.call(d3.axisBottom(x)
        .tickSize(13)
        .tickFormat(( honey_data, function(d){
            return d.average_price_per_pound;
        }),)
        .tickValues(color.range().slice(1).map(d => color.invertExtent(d)[0])))
        .select(".domain")
        .remove();

    // svg.append("g")
    //     .selectAll("path")
    //     .data(honey_data, function(d){
    //         return d.average_price_per_pound;
    //     })
    //     .enter().append("path")
    //     .attr("fill", d => color(d.average_price_per_pound))
    //     .attr("d", path)
    //     .append("title")
    //     .text(d => (d.average_price_per_pound));
    //
    // svg.append("path")
    //     .datum(honey_data, function(d){
    //         return d.average_price_per_pound;
    //     })
    //     .attr("fill", "none")
    //     .attr("stroke", "white")
    //     .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
    //     .attr("d", path);


});

// Add most popular cities across the US with a circle changing accordingly to the size of the population
function draw_cities(){
    d3.json( 'data/us-city.json', function( city_data ){
        map.selectAll("circle")
            .data(city_data)
            .enter()
            .append( "circle" )
            .style( "fill", "#9D497A" )
            .style( "opacity", 0.8 )
            .attr( 'cx', function( d ){
                return projection([ d.longitude, d.latitude ])[0];
            })
            .attr( 'cy', function( d ){
                return projection([ d.longitude, d.latitude ])[1];
            })
            .attr( 'r', function(d){
                return Math.sqrt( parseInt(d.population) * 0.00005 );
            })
            .append( 'title' )
            .text(function(d){
                return d.city;
            });
    });
}


// Panning
d3.selectAll( '#buttons button.panning' ).on( 'click', function(){
    var x           =   0;
    var y           =   0;
    var distance    =   100;
    var direction   =   d3.select( this ).attr( 'class' ).replace( 'panning ', '' );

    if( direction === "up" ){
        y           +=  distance; // Increase y offset
    }else if( direction === "down" ){
        y           -=  distance; // Decrease y offset
    }else if( direction === "left" ){
        x           +=  distance; // Increase x offset
    }else if( direction === "right" ){
        x           -=  distance; // Decrease x offset
    }

    map.transition()
        .call( zoom_map.translateBy, x, y );
});


// Zooming
d3.selectAll( '#buttons button.zooming' ).on( 'click', function(){
    var scale       =   1;
    var direction   =   d3.select(this).attr("class").replace( 'zooming ', '' );

    if( direction === "in" ){
        scale       =  1.25;
    }else if(direction === "out"){
        scale       =  0.75;
    }

    map.transition()
        .call(zoom_map.scaleBy, scale);
});


// Slider
function update(year){
     slider.property("value", year);
     d3.select(".year").text(year);
     // honeyyear.style("fill", function(d) {
     //      return color(d.properties.years[year][0].rate)
     };


var slider = d3.select(".slider")
    .append("input")
    .attr("type", "range")
    .attr("min", 2009)
    .attr("max", 2013)
    .attr("step", 1)
    .on("input", function() {
         var year = this.value;
         update(year);
     });

update(2013);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

d3.json and other fetching tools from D3 makes the fetch and returns a promise that you can use to update your data based on the slider input event. Check this fiddle to see how it works.

http://jsfiddle.net/9rkc0nuL/

```
const getData = value => d3.json(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${value}`)
const slider = document.getElementById('start')

slider.addEventListener('input', event => getData(event.target.value).then(
  data => {
    const display = document.getElementById('display')
    display.innerText = data.title
  }
))
```

If you are looking for the specific solution to your problem this piece of code should solve it:

```
let updateYear = year => {
    slider.attr("value", year);
    d3.select(".year").text(year);
}

var slider = d3.select(".slider")
    .append("input")
    .attr("type", "range")
    .attr("min", 2009)
    .attr("max", 2013)
    .attr("step", 1)
    .on("input", function() {
        const value = this.value
        updateYear(this.value)
        d3.json(`data/HoneyProduction-${value}.json`)
            .then(data => {
                // Do whatever you need with your data
            })         
     });

updateYear(2013)
```